# Scale bitmap around center pivot

Tags: android, bitmap

I need to make an icon on Home screen from image. I use the standart code for this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);
int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
// Determine how much to scale down the image
final int scaleFactor = (int) Math.max(photoW/app_icon_size, photoH/app_icon_size);

// Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill needed sizes
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);

return bitmap;
```

But because of using integer rather than float for `inSampleSize` i have to downscale bitmap a little more to fit it exactly to sizes i need:

```
final float aspectRatio = (float) bitmap.getWidth()/bitmap.getHeight();
final int finalW = (aspectRatio < 1 ? (int) (app_icon_size*aspectRatio) : app_icon_size);
final int finalH = (aspectRatio > 1 ? (int) (app_icon_size/aspectRatio) : app_icon_size);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, finalW, finalH, false);
```

Everything is nice exept it is scaled from its 0,0 point. So i tried to use `createBitmap` with Matrix instead of `createScaledBitmap`:

```
Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
scaleMatrix.setScale((float) finalW/bitmap.getWidth(), (float) finalH/bitmap.getHeight(), (float) bitmap.getWidth()/2, (float) bitmap.getHeight()/2);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), scaleMatrix, false);
```

But nothing changed, it still scales from 0,0. This is banal question i guess, but most solutions on Stack and other resources concern Canvas and View but i need to scale Bitmap itslef.